# Copy button from Label (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Copy button from Label.

I have code for the calculator but I can not figure out how to do it so that when I click on the button, the number with the Label is copied.
Or how can I make it so that when I press long it appears to copy:

[image: Photo1]"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayResultLabel: UILabel!
    var stillTyping = false
    var dotIsPlaced = false
    var firstOperand: Double = 0
    var secondOperand: Double = 0
    var operationSign: String = ""

    var currentInput: Double {
        get {
            return Double (displayResultLabel.text!)!
        }
        set {
            let value = "\(newValue)"
            let ValueArray = (value.components(separatedBy:"."))
            if ValueArray[1] == "0" {
                displayResultLabel.text = "\(ValueArray[0])"
            } else {
                displayResultLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
            }
            stillTyping = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let number = sender.currentTitle!

        if stillTyping {
            if (displayResultLabel.text?.characters.count)! < 20 {
                displayResultLabel.text = displayResultLabel.text! + number
            }
        } else {
            displayResultLabel.text = number
            stillTyping = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func twoOperandsSignPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        operationSign = sender.currentTitle!
        firstOperand = currentInput
        stillTyping = false
        dotIsPlaced = false
    }

    func operateWithTwoOperands(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
        currentInput = operation(firstOperand, secondOperand)
        stillTyping = false
    }

    @IBAction func equalitySignPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if stillTyping {
            secondOperand = currentInput
        }

        dotIsPlaced = false

        switch operationSign {
        case "+":
            operateWithTwoOperands{$0 + $1}
        case "-":
            operateWithTwoOperands{$0 - $1}
        case "×":
            operateWithTwoOperands{$0 * $1}
        case "÷":
            operateWithTwoOperands{$0 / $1}
        default: break
        }
    }

    @IBAction func dotButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if stillTyping && !dotIsPlaced {
            displayResultLabel.text = displayResultLabel.text! + "."
            dotIsPlaced = true
        } else if !stillTyping && !dotIsPlaced {
            displayResultLabel.text = "0."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When debugging your code, which line does something unexpected?

Comment: @Smartcat ?????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer both of your questions.

**The first question:** How to press a button that can copy the text that is being displayed on the `UILabel`?

**Answer:**

```
@IBAction func yourButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = yourLabel.text
}
```

**The second question:** How to long-press on the `UILabel` that shows the "Copy" action?

**Answer:**

To make `UILabel` copyable we need to create a custom class that is a subclass of `UILabel`. Temporarily called `CopyableLabel`:

```
import UIKit

class CopyableLabel: UILabel {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = text
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(copy(_:))
    }
}

// MARK: Actions methods
extension CopyableLabel {

    func longPressGestureActionHandler(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        becomeFirstResponder()

        let menu = UIMenuController.shared

        if !menu.isMenuVisible {
            menu.setTargetRect(bounds, in: self)
            menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Helper methods
extension CopyableLabel {

    func sharedInit() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressGestureActionHandler(_:))))
    }
}
```

And use a `CopyableLabel` instead of a pure `UILabel`:

```
let yourLabel: CopyableLabel = CopyableLabel()
```

If you use the Interface Builder, make sure you've defined the base class of your Label:

[image]

Comment: Congratulation! It's a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement copy and paste with `UIPasteboard`. You can read and write values over it's property `string`, e.g.:

```
displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string
```

pastes the current value from the pasteboard into your label, and

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = displayResultLabel.text
```

copies the value from label to the pasteboard.