# Button for copying from Label

Tags: ios, swift3

I have code to copy the numbers from the Label.

How it's called?

How can I make that when I click on a button, it appears that on the photo

[image]

```
@IBAction func copybutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = displayResultLabel.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code -

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = sender.title(for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Where should it be inserted?

Comment: Inside the IBAction method for your button click.

Comment: The app crashes

Comment: "@IBAction func copybutton (_ отправитель: UIButton) {UIPasteboard.general.string = sender.title (для: UIControlState.normal)}"

Comment: You could post your crashlog, otherwise it's difficult to understand what going wrong.

Comment: You need to show more code when you click button and where you called that code etc.

Comment: @AbhishekJain The app no longer crashes but when I click the button it copies the name of the button

Comment: what you want to copy?

Comment: @AbhishekJain Number from Label. All my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662182/copy-button-from-label-ios